# How to find multiple minimum values in excel without repeating?

Tags: excel, minimum

Image:

[image]

In Excel, column J has a formula `IF(H32>0,D32,MIN($S$32:S32))`. For `MIN($S$32:S32))`, it is finding the lowest value in `column S`. However, if you see cell `J39`, it repeats using the same minimum value in `J37`.

I am looking to modify the function I created where the minimum value won't repeat itself. For example, the next minimum after `57.87` in `column S` is `75.82`. Therefore, `75.82` should appear in cell `J39`.

Comment: http://www.contextures.com/excel-functions-rank.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RANK` formula for this. With `RANK`, you can choose the n-th minimum value from `Column S`.